# How to run a Cron on particular button click on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cron, backend

I want to run a Cron on particular button click which I have to create in Magento Backend.

Basically i want to run cron when i click that button and it will take some data from a txt file and create a new product in Magento 2.

Or any other any because if the txt file has so much product then it will hung up the Magento Panel if i create that from admin side so my idea is to run that in background any idea of doing that.

My Csv file

```
col1    col2    col3
abc     123     xyz
abc     234     xyz
abc     456     xyz
abc     789     xyz
def     567     xyz
def     223     xyz
```

**now i have added only some rows from csv now i have to created product name like ex: abc-123-xyz like this name.

I have get the name of the product like this from csv file in a controller but if my csv has 1000 rows then the controller took very long time to do that.
How to achieve that or should i use controller ?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you create action which call on that button?

Comment: This makes no sense. Cron Jobs are made to execute a task automatically in certain intervals. If you want to do something after pressing a button, then you need to call method not a cron.

Comment: it will call an cron or controller i think but i'm bit confused what to use as on creating more products it will stuck i think and on cron how will i managed to run that on my particular button click @DhirenVasoya

Comment: If i call a method then on creating more than 1000 product at one time it will stuck or any issue like timeout @Black

Comment: @Prits have you create the actions? And your crone is ready?

Comment: @Prits, then your method is bad or you have bad PHP settings.

Comment: No not yet will do once once decided how to proceed.@DhirenVasoya

Comment: Please suggest how to proceed that part @Black

Comment: @Prits, It would be a start if you show your code.

Comment: I have updated my question about starting please check if it is good or anything wrong so please tell me i will do that @Black